# How do I prove that this sequence is monotonic?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I've been given the following series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^∞(-1)^n\frac{n-1}{n+1} \frac{1}{ n^{1/2}}$$

Now, I want to perform the Leibniz test on the mentioned series. However, I can't find any proof that $a_n$  is monotonic and decreasing. Can anyone help?

Comment: That [boils down](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28-1+%2B+n%29%2F%28Sqrt%5Bn%5D+%281+%2B+n%29%29%3E%28-1+%2B+n%2B1%29%2F%28Sqrt%5Bn%2B1%5D+%282+%2B+n%29%29) to a 3rd order inequality

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=\dfrac{x-1}{x+1}\cdot\dfrac{1}{x^{1/2}}$, then $g(x):=\log f(x)=\log (x-1)-\log(x+1)-\dfrac{1}{2}\log x$, and $g'(x)=\dfrac{-(x-2)^{2}+5}{2x(x-1)(x+1)}<0$ for large $x$, so $g$ is decreasing and also that $f$.

Answer (score 1):

Without derivative, we need to show that

$$\frac{n}{n+2} \frac{1}{ (n+1)^{1/2}}\le \frac{n-1}{n+1} \frac{1}{ n^{1/2}}$$

$$\frac{n}{n+2}\frac{n+1}{n-1} \le  \frac{ (n+1)^{1/2}}{ n^{1/2}}$$

$$\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{(n+2)^2(n-1)^2} \le  1+\frac1n$$

$$\frac{n^4+2n^3+n^2}{n^4+2n^3-3n^2-4n+4} \le  1+\frac1n$$

$$\frac{n^4+2n^3-3n^2-4n+4+4n^2+4n-4}{n^4+2n^3-3n^2-4n+4} \le  1+\frac1n$$

$$1+\frac{4n^2+4n-4}{n^4+2n^3-3n^2-4n+4} \le  1+\frac1n$$

$$\frac{4n^2+4n-4}{n^4+2n^3-3n^2-4n+4} \le  \frac1n$$

$$n^4+2n^3-3n^2-4n+4\ge 4n^3+4n^2-4n $$

$$n^4-2n^3-7n^2+4\ge 0 $$

which is true eventually.

Comment: Thanks. What does "eventually" mean?

Comment: It means that it becomes always true for any $n$ as $n\ge n_0$.

Comment: Thanks for your output. I thought this has to be true for all natural numbers and that's why it made no sense to me. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed for the convergence/divergence of any series what we need is that the property (any property) holds eventually. Maybe we could also simplify it. You can try maybe!

Comment: For example we could also stop here with the proof $$1+\frac{4n^2+4n-4}{n^4+2n^3-3n^2-4n+4} \le  1+\frac1n $$

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=\dfrac{x-1}{x+1}\cdot\dfrac{1}{x^{1/2}} \implies f'(x)=\frac{1+4x-x^2}{2 x^{3/2} (x+1)^2}=-\frac{(x-2-\sqrt 5) (x-2+\sqrt 5) }{2 x^{3/2} (x+1)^2}$$ which is negative as soon as $x >2+\sqrt 5$.

Using @user'solution

$$n^4-2n^3-7n^2+4\ge 0\implies (n+1)(n^3-3 n^2-4 n+4)\ge 0$$ and, by inspection, the cubic polynomial is positive as soon as $n \ge  4$